# How to select a node in Tree based on XML node property?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a tree im my mxml that uses a XMLListCollection as dataProvider. It´s XML is like:

```
    <list>
      <conta nome="Plano de Contas" id="1">
        <conta nome="Creditos" id="2" />
          <conta nome="Vendas" id="4" />
          <conta nome="Juros" id="5" />
        <conta nome="Debitos" id="3" />
      </conta>
    </list>
```

How can I make the node for, say, id==4 visible AND selected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var xml:XML =
<list>
  <conta nome="Plano de Contas" id="1">
    <conta nome="Creditos" id="2" />
      <conta nome="Vendas" id="4" />
      <conta nome="Juros" id="5" />
    <conta nome="Debitos" id="3" />
  </conta>
</list>;

//find node conta with id=4 using xml selectors
var node:XML = xml.descendants("conta").(@id == 4)[0];
tree.selectedItem = node;
```

You might need to open node parents if they are not, mx:Tree might not do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For selection you can use, this.myTree.selectedIndex=4, that done, it should become visible automatically.

Comment: here myTree is the id you have given to the tree object.

Comment: It doesn´t work. Please note that the id is an attribute of the XML node.